# HTML + FORM + INPUT + REMPLACE code + PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, actionscript-3, get

I have a file named "test.html" with the code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>welcome people<p>
        <h1>nice</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to create a copy of "test.html" and replace:

```
<p>welcome people<p>
```

and

```
<h1>nice</h1>
```

with another code.

So I need to create a form with 3 inputs:

- input 1 : name of the copy (expemple test01.html)
- input 2 : code which replace `<p>welcome people</p>`
- input 3 : code which replace `<h1>nice</h1>`

I need following `form` in a file named (control.html) with code :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="get" action="process.php">
            <input name="titlecopyfile">
            <input name="code1">
            <input name="code2">
            <input type="submite">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need the code for:

- test.html
- control.html
- process.php

Comment: What does ActionScript 3 have to do with this?

Comment: The functions you need to use are `file_get_contents()`, `str_replace()`, and `file_put_contents()`.

Comment: What is `code1` and `code2`? Give some examples...

Comment: nice but can you write for me the code for : process.php only

Comment: d.coder ok give me a minutes

Comment: code1 : is a code wich i can put it in input 
exemple (<h3> nice job </h3>)
if i write this in the input with name="code1"
it will copy test.html file and remplace (<p>welcome people<p>) with (<h3> nice job </h3>) .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

Test.html :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>welcome people<p>
        <h1>nice</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Control.html :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="process.php">
            <input name="titlecopyfile">
            <input name="code1">
            <input name="code2">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Process.php :

```
<?php
// Get all request parameters
$filename = $_REQUEST['titlecopyfile'];
$code1 = $_REQUEST['code1'];
$code2 = $_REQUEST['code2'];

// Read existing file content in a variable
$testHtml = file_get_contents('test.html');

// Replace desired strings with actual values
$testHtml = str_replace(array('<p>welcome people<p>', '<h1>nice</h1>'), array($code1, $code2), $testHtml);

// Write file on disk physically and save it as specified name
file_put_contents($filename, $testHtml);
```

Comment: Are you sure,
form attribute methode? Or method?

Comment: you are awsome 
this will be very very helpfull

Comment: Sorry, I just copied this code from the question itself. Now fixed in both places.

Comment: Thanks, Don't forget to upvote and accept it as answer if it worked for you. Enjoy...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST`?

Comment: It works for both the case `GET` or `POST`. If you are very sure that form will be submitted only with `POST` method then you can use `POST` as in this case. But in some case, it may not be known, by what method form was submitted so it is my general practice to use `$_REQUEST` over `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

Comment: Fatal error: on line 8
 Call to undefined function file_get_content()

Comment: Sorry, function name was incorrect. Code updated. It was replaced by my spelling auto-correct plugin.